# Referer in URLConnection doesn't work

Tags: android, http, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I would like to fetch a html page with post method. First I use HttpClient, it doesn't give the right response,  then I add `Header` with a `Referer`, it works well but too slow. So I plan to use URLConnection, I also add `Referer` to the `Header`, this time it doesn't return what I want.

HttpClient:

```
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(WhutGlobal.URL_HEADER_STR + "xscj_gc.aspx?xh=" + WhutGlobal.USER_ID + "&xm=" + WhutGlobal.USER_NAME + "&gnmkdm=N121605");
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httppost.setHeader("Referer", WhutGlobal.URL_HEADER_STR + "xscj_gc.aspx?xh=" + WhutGlobal.USER_ID + "&xm=" + WhutGlobal.USER_NAME + "&gnmkdm=N121605");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                byte  bytearray[] = new  byte[800000];
                 int current= -1;
                 int i=0;  
                 while((current=bis.read())!=-1) {
                     bytearray[i] =(byte) current;
                      i++;
               }
              html = new String (bytearray,"GB2312");
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
```

URLConnection:

```
 URL url = new URL(WhutGlobal.URL_HEADER_STR + "xscj_gc.aspx?xh=" + WhutGlobal.USER_ID + "&xm=" + WhutGlobal.USER_NAME + "&gnmkdm=N121605");
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
         urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
         urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
         urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
         urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Referer", WhutGlobal.URL_HEADER_STR + "xscj_gc.aspx?xh=" + WhutGlobal.USER_ID + "&xm=" + WhutGlobal.USER_NAME + "&gnmkdm=N121605");
         DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                   urlConnection.getOutputStream ());
         wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
         wr.flush ();
         wr.close ();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no significant difference in speed between `HttpClient` and `URLConnection` methods of obtainin html ... it can depends on connection speed (3G/Wifi)but

HttpPost solution can work slow because you're using:

`while((current=bis.read())!=-1) ...`

instead this **STUPID snipet**(in this case reading byte by byte is really not efficient) use:

`html = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "GB2312")`

about HttpURLConnection ... it really depends on what you send in urlParameters ... and you should not use `DataOutputStream` in this case

Comment: Thanks for your tips, it is now faster, can you say more about URLConnection, what's wrong with DataOutputStream?